# Crypt function generetes the same hash for the same password

Tags: php, hash, password-protection

I'm trying to create an hashing function that, given a random salt, generates a password hash from it.

The problem is, that, if I enter the same password for two different users, the hash generated is the same for both.

Waht might be the problem?

```
public function generateSalt()
{       


     return $salt = substr(sha1(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 32);
}

public function pwdEncrypt($password, $salt)
{       

    $hash = crypt($password, '$2a$' . $salt . '$');     
    return $hash;
}

public function registerUser($nome, $email, $password, $permitions, $active)
{



    $this->nome = $nome;
    $this->email = $email;


    $salt = $this->generateSalt();


    $this->password = $this->pwdEncrypt($password, $salt);

   //INSERT METHODS BELOW
}
```

Comment: Show us how you call `pwdEncript()`. By the way, the correct spelling is "Encrypt"

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thank you for your notice. I've edited the post with the info you've asked

Comment: Make sure that you actually pass $password and $salt, it is possible that no values are being passed for these variables and all you are getting is the `crypt()` of `$2a$` and `$`

Comment: @Austin, I've tested that, already. Different passwords generete different hashes. Otherwise the hash would be the same for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you use `crypt` with blowfish (`$2a$`)

You need to specify the strength, and the salt at the end.

Try this `crypt($password, '$2a$08$'.$salt);`

Obviously increase the strength to improve security, at the expense of processing time.

I should also add, if you are using a PHP version greater than 5.3.7, you should use `$2y$` for your blowfish algorithm, as an attack for `$2a$` was discovered in 2011.

Comment: @JoãoDias: Please see my edit. There's some guidance for you over your choice of algorithm.

Comment: I've ssen, however, $2y$ doesn't seem to work... I'm running PHP 5.3.5 on localhost

Comment: Your PHP version is probably too low then (and you really *should* upgrade if it is that low)

Comment: Is there any way to do the encryption based on PHP Version?

Comment: @JoãoDias: You can use `version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7') >= 0` to check the version.

Answer (score 2):

`crypt()` will return a hashed string using the standard Unix DES-based algorithm.

Standard DES-based hash has a **two character salt** from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z".

Since in your case the first **three** characters of the salt are always the same, the salt used is always the same.

Use

```
return $salt = substr(sha1(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 2);
```

and

```
$hash = crypt($password, $salt);
```

Comment: If your system has `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` available and this is what you wanted to do, then Leigh's answer is the way to go.

Comment: I was going to ask that! Thank you for your effort! It's still a good valid answer ;)